# Rails 403 error when combining with Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So if I place an `index.html` file inside of my `public/` rails folder, I can see the contents. However, if I remove it, then I get the following error from Apache's `error.log` file:

```
[Wed Sep 19 22:43:29.802178 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 52250] [client 172.16.38.1:49395] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/user/rails_app/public/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Any idea what I might be missing here? I seem to be only one or two steps away from getting Rails to work with Apache. Here's my configuration file for the site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/user/rails_app/public
  <Directory /home/user/rails_app/public>
    AllowOverride All
        Options -MultiViews
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
    ErrorLog /home/user/rails_app/log/error.log
    CustomLog /home/user/rails_app/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

What exactly am I missing that's not allowing this process to work? Thanks for any input.

It seems that `libapache2-mod-passenger` is already installed, but Apache can't load it for some strange reason:

```
[user:ubuntu:.../rails_app/public]$ sudo apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-passenger
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libapache2-mod-passenger is already the newest version (1:5.3.4-1~bionic1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

but trying to load it doesn't work

```
[user:ubuntu:.../rails_app/public]$ sudo a2enmod passenger                                                                                                                                                10:54PM/09.19
ERROR: Module passenger does not exist!
```

Doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I don't think the `apache` module is installed. Can you try running this `passenger-install-apache2-module`. Also, I don't see any passengerRoot and LoadModule information in apache configuration.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna When I ran the passenger check to verify passenger and Ruby, they both came back as configured correctly. Or is this something else I'm missing?

Comment: For the `autoindex` error, I think it is because, `Directory` directive is appended to `DocumentRoot`. Can you try `DocumentRoot /home/user/rails_app/public`

`<Directory ~ "/.*/">
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly, I am suspecting passenger is not running. These may help you:

Seems to be your passenger is not enabled.

can you please run:

```
$which passenger-config
```

the above command will return like this

```
/opt/passenger/bin/passenger-config
```

and run 
       $rvm use XXXX

set the ruby to passenger:

here I am taking the ($which passenger-config):/opt/passenger/bin/passenger-config

```
$/opt/passenger/bin/passenger-config --ruby-command
```

Will set the ruby to the path.

Can you run:

```
sudo a2enmod passenger
```

on success, do the

```
$sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I can't run `rvm use` because of this error: `RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.`. I'm using the zsh shell and seems like trying to run this even in bash is throwing PATH errors.

Comment: if you don't have multiple versions of ruby, don't run RVM use, continue other steps

Comment: So I was able to run the `/usr/bin/passenger-config` command, which gave me a command to a path to ruby. I tried running `sudo a2enmod passenger` again and it told me that the module does not exist.

Comment: Have you installed the apache passenger module?

Comment: Yep, if I try to run `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-passenger`, it gives me `libapache2-mod-passenger is already the newest version`

Comment: are you getting any errors? on $sudo service apache2 restart. Please check for the passenger config file, in that file ruby is set or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180397/discussion-between-tekuri-and-lewlsauce).

Comment: Nope. So what I just did was ran `apt get remove libapache2-mod-passenger` and just ran `passenger-install-apache2-module` and now I can enable it with `a2enmod passenger`. Absolutely NO idea why this worked or even broke in the first place, but seems to be good now.